# Corrupt OLE Object datatype records in Microsoft Access

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

```
   In my client database, i saw corrupted records for specifically Template Column(DataType : OLE Object) in Emp table. if i am trying to delete it tells "The Microsoft Jet database engine stopped the process because you and another user are attempting to change the same data at the same time". only one thing i can do remove corrupted record by deleting that row which contained corrupted record but this not suitable solution.
```

How can prevent corrupt records in access database with C# application?

[image: Corrupt OLE Object records]

Comment: You might like to read http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/corruption/causes.htm

Comment: yes i read above article, it's relate to "Corrupt Microsoft Access MDB Causes". but not getting why OLE object datatype column got corrupted.